# Can i add/copy the same Picture Content Control in multiple locations inside my word template

Tags: ms-word, office365, docx

I have a .docx word document >> and i have added a Picture Content Control named "Approver Signature" >> as shown in the attached file:-

[image]

but is there a way to copy this control and paste it inside different locations? so when i pass the image content it should appear on multiple locations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Copy method of a ContentControl object](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.copy) to implement it.

```vb
Sub CopyPictureContentControl()
    Dim cc As ContentControl, ccCopy As ContentControl
    
    ' if the Picture Content Control you want to copy is the first one
    Set cc = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
    cc.Copy
    
    Rem Place the insertion position in the position where to copy
    Selection.Paste
    
Rem the other way:
'    Set ccCopy = Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlPicture)
'    With ccCopy
'        .Title = cc.Title
'        ...
'    End With
End Sub
```

Is this what you want?